# How to filter an element from an array in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have created a function for removing an item from an array when the delete icon is pressed but the deletion is not working. Below is the code with the function that is supposed to filter an element from an array but it throws `undefined is not an object(evaluating alerts.filter)`.

```
 const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([])
  function itemRemove(item) {
        setAlerts(({ alerts }) => ({
            newalerts: alerts.filter(i => i.key !== item.key)
          }))
      }
 return (
    
        <ScrollView>
        {
          alerts  &&  alerts.map((item, i) => {
                return (
                    <ListItem key={i} bottomDivider>
                <ListItem.Content>
                    <ListItem.Title>

                        {item.CurrencyPair_Name}
                    </ListItem.Title>
                    
                    <MaterialCommunityIcons
                    name="delete"
                   onPress={() =>itemRemove(item)}
                
                    size={24}
                    color="black"
                    style={{position:"absolute", right: 3}}/> 
                </ListItem.Content>
            </ListItem>
                )
            }
            )
            
        }
        </ScrollView>
         
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

can u try this.

```
  function itemRemove(item) {
        setAlerts(prev => prev.filter(i => i.key !== item.key))
  }
```

You declared alerts as an array, not an object.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

```
function itemRemove(index) {
    const newAlerts = [...alerts];
    newAlerts.splice(index, 1);
    setAlerts(newAlerts);
}


return (
   ........
   onPress={() =>itemRemove(i)}  // send index here               
   ......      
)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [alerts, setAlerts] = useState([])

function itemRemove(item) {
    const newAlerts = alerts.filter(i => i.key !== item.key);

    setAlerts(newAlerts);
}
```